# JS Toss function using random number generator 0 to 1

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get the below to work properly:

```
function toss()
{

//If both coins come up HEADS or TAILS, the player wins. Otherwise the player loses.
//random number generator 0 to 1
//change image source using getElementById to div id coinA and coinB
//if random numbers same, set resultText innerHTML to "You Win"
//var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;

var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

var coinImg = document.querySelectorAll("#coinA, #coinB");
if (x == 0){
    coinImg.src = "images/coin0.png";
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "You Lost";
    } else {
    coinImg.src = "images/coin1.png";
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "You Win";
}


}

Here is the HTML:

<img src="images/coin1.png" id="coinA" width="100" height="100" alt="coin">
<img src="images/coin1.png" id="coinB" width="100" height="100" alt="coin">

<button type="button" onclick="toss()">Go</button> 

<div id="resultText">Press GO to play!</div>
```

At the moment it's telling me "You Lost" when both are Heads... the image for tails is coin0 and heads is coin1.

Comment: `coinImg` is a collection of up to two elements. It doesn't have a `.src` property.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that Bergi

Comment: what about `Math.random()>=0.5`?

Comment: what Bergi means is that `coinImg` is not an `img` element, but an array of two such elements. so you can't just access `coinImg.src`, because there's two of them (`coinImg[0]` and `coinImg[1]`).

Comment: @Toblerone: That you're tossing only one coin (`x`), but showing two images. It looks like you attempt to set the `.src` of both to the same file, aren't you? What did you expect to do to A and B?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select which `coinImg` you want to use, since `querySelectorAll` returns several elements

Also, you might just want to show/hide the correct coin instead ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h1kmgkrc/))

```
var x = Math.round(Math.random()); // x is always 0 or 1
var coins = document.querySelectorAll("#coinA, #coinB");

for (var i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    coins[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
}

var coin = coins[x];
coin.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
```

HTML needs to be updated too

```
<div id="coinA">
    <p>You Lost</p>
    <img src="images/coin0.png" width="100" height="100" alt="coin">
</div>

<div id="coinB">
    <p>You Win</p>
    <img src="images/coin1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="coin">
</div>
```